# Navegar pelas linhas de um arquivo txt com java

Tags: java, arquivo

Olá, tenho um arquivo txt com notas de alunos, onde cada linha representa um aluno e cada nota é separada por um ";", dessa forma:

```
5.6;9.7;1.3;8.6
9.6;8.9;8.8;7.3
3.5;1.2;6.3;4.4
```

Tenho que calcular a média de cada um por um programa em Java.
Fiz um método que lê esses dados e retorna uma única string com eles.

```
public static String Read(String path){
        String content = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader readArq = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line = "";
            
            try {
                line = readArq.readLine();
                while(line!=null){
                    content += line + "\n";
                    line = readArq.readLine();
                }
                
                readArq.close();
                return content;
                
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return "Erro: Não foi possível ler o arquivo!";
            }
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            return "Erro: Arquivo não encontrado!";
        }
    }
```

Porém não estou sabendo como pegar cada linha para poder calcular. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Como separar cada valor na linha e converté-los para float, também sei fazer. Só não estou conseguido pegar as linhas

Answer (score -1):

Depois que lemos cada linha, precisamos usar o `String#split` para separar as notas.

Eu fiz um exemplo comentado com código compatível com Java 8, veja:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

class Program {
  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("notas.txt");

    // Pega todas as linhas
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

    for (String line : lines) {
      // Quebra a linha pelo ponto e virgula
      String[] notes = line.split(";");

      double total = 0;

      // Soma cada nota na linha
      for (String note : notes) {
        total += Double.parseDouble(note);
      }

      // Pega a média
      double average = total / notes.length;

      // Mostra o resultado
      System.out.println("Média: " + average);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Com esse Files.readAllLines eu não preciso dessa classe que criei para ler o arquivo, certo? Aí armazenando as linhas do arquivo na lista, basta fazer um loop para interagir com elas. A parte do split eu tenho noção, o restante que estava um pouco confuso, pq não pensei em armazenar em lista. Muito obrigada mesmo, me ajudou bastante

Comment: Isso mesmo, o Files.readAllLines nos economiza várias linhas, é muito bom quando vc quer ler arquivos não muito grandes.